# Quand utiliser courir et quand parcourir?

Tags: sens, usage, verbes

Je suis en train d'étudier le français avec Babbel et j'ai trouvé la phrase suivante :

> I run the 42 km in 3 hours

J'ai pensé la traduire utilisant le verbe courir mais la traduction donnée par Babbel est :

> Je parcours les 42 kilomètres en 3 heures

**Quand dois-je utiliser parcourir et quand courir ?** **Y a-t-il une différence pour cette phrase ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En général, **parcourir** sera utilisé pour démontrer une distance faite. Elle peut être fait par la course, en voiture, train etc... La personne précisera la moyen de transport dans le contexte. La différence de **courir** est vraiment l'action de se déplacer avec ses jambes. Dans ce que tu as écris, ils auraient dû utiliser **courir**.

Comment: Si l’on parle d’une course/distance déjà couru est-ce que “parcourir” serait un peu plus acceptable ? par exemple » : « J’ai parcouru les 42 kilomètres en 3 heures». (ou si l’on ajoute la notion de « normalement » [en temps présent]  ? : e.g., « Normalement je parcours les 42 kilomètres en 3 heures »)  Je demande ça car en anglais « cover » marcherait dans ces 2 exemples (avec le contexte compris), mais « run » serait bcp mieux quand on parle carrément dans le présent : (e.g., I am [currently] running that distance in/[at a pace of] 3 heures)

Comment: Comme j'ai dit, tu peux dire **j'ai parcouru** mais hors contexte, la personne n'aura aucune idée de comment vous les avez parcouru. Mais si le contexte est dit, parcouru sonne beaucoup mieux.

Answer (score 1):

[parcourir](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/parcourir) means *to travel*, *to roam*,... and thus put an emphasis on the path which has been traveled and gives no hint on how it has been traveled (you could use that precise sentence if you were traveling by car and got stuck in a traffic jam).

[courir](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/courir) means *to run* and so put an emphasis on the way you were traveling.